# Realtime Database ref change can' t detect

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created a Db. Name Tomris
Below that is a 'Cumle': "Sentence". Whatever I do here does not happen.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEKAk.png
[image]

What I want is Trigger work when the sentence changes. But I couldn't.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
  

exports.DBTrigger = functions.database.ref('tomris-d96a7/Cumle')
    .onWrite( (change, context) => {
        const afterData = change.after.data();
        console.log(afterData);
        console.log ("onur");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included the name of your database in the Cloud Functions trigger, which is not needed and in fact means your Function is now looking at a non-existing path.

To trigger on the correct path, only include that path in the Function definition:

```
exports.DBTrigger = functions.database.ref('Cumle')
  ...
```